# Is there an better than Adobe RGB monitor?

Tags: color, color-spaces, monitors

All monitors I see claim 99 percent of the Adobe RGB and that's it

Is there something better? We are seeing 14 bit HDR televisions these day which uses 14 bit altough I am not sure what exactly they use. Some SMTPE CIE standard or some manufacturer standard. Too bad they don't have glare shields.

Comment: Higher bit depth does not always equate to a wider color space. It could also mean more "steps" in the same or even in a smaller space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All monitors I see claim 99 percent of the Adobe RGB

You are actually seeing some good monitors then. But the vast majority are below that claim.

We enter the realm of Wide gamut (Adobe RGB is actually one of them).

Although it is for a different use (video color grading) the NTCS standard has a bit more gamut to the red color.

And then we can find [ProPhoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProPhoto_RGB_color_space) REC, like [REC2020, REC100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._2020) and [Adobe Wide Gamut RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-gamut_RGB_color_space) for example.

More bits per channel are to provide more dynamic range, and yes, sometimes also means wider gamut.

But probably the question is if you actually need a wider gamut. The answer would be depending on the field you are working in.

It is hard fo find monitors that actually even mention those color spaces. For marketing purposes, it is better to say that you cover 99% of a smaller color space than a smaller % of a bigger one.

Comment: that doesn't actually answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

## *Better Isn't Necessarily Bigger*

First, it depends on what you mean by "better."

I can give you a rational argument that sRGB is better than AdobeRGB, despite sRGB being a "smaller" gamut:

#### sRGB is better than AdobeRGB for 8 bit images as sRGB's smaller gamut makes better use of the lower bit depth and reduced Delta E errors.

If you mean "bigger" keep in mind that if you use a larger gamut colorspace than sRGB, you ALSO need to use a higher bit depth to have reasonable and minimum distance interpolation between values.

That said, DCI P3 is the colorspace used in theaters. And that system uses 12 bits with a gamma of 1/2.6

If you have a home cinema, then you might think you want a P3 projector or monitor — though what are you going to play through it? There are maybe a handful of Blurays mastered in that larger colorspace. Regular HD is still Rec709 (same color primaries as sRGB).

There is progress being made with HDR monitors, such as for Rec2020.

### BUT

What is your specific application? What are you doing? If your work is not using bright highly saturated colors, then sRGB is very likely ideal. You only need a larger space when your image "won't fit", i.e. colors are being clipped.

Answer (score 1):

DCI-P3 color gamut in a Rec.2020 color space sounds good to me, then you are UHD compatible. HDR capability with a SMPTE.2084 EOCF on top of that is even better.